# Facebook share link image, behaves different depending on users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app, and I am able to share links, and image for this link, on FB, using FB.ui.

The point is, depending for the FB account who is sharing the link, I can get big image, or small one.

This is a real pain, because if I configure and send big image, on the accounts which uses small one, the image is cropped, and also on the other way.

I am sending, as far as I know, all known parameters for FB, but the result is the same.

```
FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:title': title,
                            'og:description': description,
                            'og:url': invitationLink,
                            'og:image:url': imgPath,
                            'og:image:width': imgWidth,
                            'og:image:height': imgHeight,
                            'og:image:alt': 'refer a friend by lottoland'
                        }
                    })
                });
```

What could be wrong here? How can I "force" facebook to always use same type of image?

Thanks anyone for the support.

Comment: You can not really _force_ this. All you can do is follow the best practices outlined in the docs regarding image size and aspect ratio - and hope for the best. But Facebook might still decide to display the same external object differently in different situations. So you best stick to images that still “make sense” to the user if cropped to a square, and don’t put any actually relevant information outside of that center square.

Comment: This is what I was thinking... as this is more or less what was able to get form doc, but on the other hand, I was expecting some "hack" to force image to be there.

Thanks anyway CBroe